# How to monitor client version distribution parsed from user-agent headers?

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a native app that is configured to include a version number in the `user-agent` request header in a regex-parseable format. I'd like to include a metric in a Cloud Monitoring dashboard that shows me a distribution of major/minor versions (and perhaps patch versions?) of the total requests over a period.

What I'm ideally looking for is a histogram or stacked bar chart of the share of each major/minor version as a percentage of the total requests in that time period.

I can set up a logs-based metric based on the major/minor version but the only way to display it in a dashboard is as a heatmap and that's not a proper representation.

Answer (score 0):

Google Monitoring, previously called stack driver, by default allows you to configure dashboards for the custom metrics you are selecting from the log files. However, if these dashboards are being useful to plot your data in a desired format you can use python code libraries and create your own custom dashboards displaying your custom data. Google-cloud-monitoring-dashboards python package helps you in creating your custom dashboards, refer to its [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-monitoring-dashboards/) for more details.